# Alternative for Teamviewer?

Tags: ssh, gui, remote-desktop, sharing, teamviewer

As one might know, Teamviewer has no native support for Linux. Although Teamviewer's marketing guys keep telling it runs fine with wine and stuff I experienced one problem after another.
Is there some other (preferably open-source) solution for sharing my desktop?
What about some software for connecting and manipulating a distant desktop? I tried to get some X window data over ssh but it was unstable and hang up often. Additionally most software "denied" grabbing its X output.

EDIT: I am interested in "helping friends" and especially in sharing my desktop for conferences.

Comment: What do you want to do? Manage your home server? Or help friends?

Comment: In fact there is: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx

Comment: @the_Seppi but still, it's runing trough wine :/ even tough it's deb package... @ ascenator it will be best to check yourself http://alternativeto.net/software/teamviewer/?platform=linux, what works for somebody, might not work for someone else ... For example I'm using teamviewer without issues

Comment: Could Chrome remote desktop extension be good enough for you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a software recommendation which is handled at out sister site http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

For Linux the obvious solution that comes to mind is [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com) which has been the leader pretty much for the last 10 years with regards to remote access for Linux.